# Extended adjoint of Volterra operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces, integral-operators

Let $V$ be a Volterra operator on $L^2 [0,1]$.

Does there exist a nonzero operator $X $ satisfying the following system

$VX=XV^∗$, where $V^∗$ is the adjoint of the Volterra operator?

$$ V(f) (x) =\int_0^x f(t) dt$$

$$ V^*(f) (x) =\int_x^1 f(t) dt$$.

We know that $V$ not (self-adjoint, normal, quasi normal).

Comment: $X(f)(s)=f(1-s)$ seems to work.

Comment: And this operator is self-adjoint.

Comment: Also, in general, if you have a solution $X$, then $Y=X+X^*$ is a self-adjoint solution.

Comment: Good idea,  we will try. Giorgio.                               Every operators can by write $T+T^*$ is self-adjoint.  So this trivial. Mr. Christian.